# ProFtpd - per ip based configuration DefaultRoot

Tags: ftp

I use proftpd server.

I want one account (login/password) used for multiple clients.

I want a different configuration directory (Default Root) for each IP.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `DefaultRoot` directive per:

- "virtual host", i.e. per server-side IP address - contain the directive in `VirtualHost`
- user group (using "group expression")

So, you **cannot** change it per source IP address.

See documentation for [`DefaultRoot` directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_auth.html#DefaultRoot).